# Define the distance $d\left(\mathbf{x},S\right)$ from a number $x$ to a set $S$ in $\mathbb R$ to be the infimum of {$ |x-y| : y\in S$}

Tags: real-analysis

### Full question:

Define the distance $d\left(\mathbf{x},S\right)$ from a number $x$ to a set $S$ in $\mathbb R$ to be the infimum of

$A=$ { $|x-y| : y\in S$ }.

1. Show that if $S$ is closed and $x \not\in S$, then $d\left(\mathbf{x},S\right)>0$.
2. Show that if $S$ is compact then the infimum above is a minimum ($x \not\in S$ still.)

### My work thus far:

1. Suppose  $inf(A)=0$ $\iff$ $0\leq|x-y|$ $\forall x\not\in S$ and $\forall y\in S$

However, observe that $|x-y|=0 \iff x=y$, which is impossible since $x\not\in S$ and $y\in S$. Thus, $inf(A)>0 \iff d(x,S)>0$

2. I am having difficulty proving the infimum is also a minimum. If $x\in S$, the solution would be trivial.

I suspect I need to couple the fact that $S$ is compact with the IVT, but I believe that would require me to prove that $A$ is continuous -- which I am unsure of how to approach. Any help or tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Think about an open interval $(0,1)$ and $0$. Then $d(0,(0,1))=0$. But $0\notin (0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1., remember that there is an infimum in the defintion, so your argument is not complete.

For 2., consider the function $d_x:S \to \Bbb{R}:s\mapsto d(x,s)$. By definition, $d(x,S)=inf(Im(d_x))$. But $S$ is compact so $Im(d_x)$ is compact so...

Comment: You're right; I completely neglected that fact. Now I am confused on 1, so let me see if I understand (I edited my problem to make it easier to view):

Suppose  $inf(A)=0$ $\iff$ $0\leq|x-y|$ $\forall x\not\in S$ and $\forall y\in S$ 

However, observe that $|x-y|=0 \iff x=y$, which is impossible since $x\not\in S$ and $y\in S$. Thus, $inf(A)>0 \iff d(x,S)>0$